# Sum of all rows by column in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DklEl.png)

How do i  make it that i sum all the rows in pca by peid?

The final result should be

```
pea| pca | peid
----------------
 5 |  1  |  1
10 |  6  |  3
```

My query for the first table(the image) is:

```
select peA, pca, peID
from ( select PE."Amount" as peA, PC."Amount" as pcA, PE."Id" as peID from "ProductEntry" as PE
         join "User" U on U."Id" = PE."UserId"
         left join "ProductConsummation" PC on PC."ProductEntryId" = PE."Id"
    where "UserId" = 1 and PE."Status" = 'Active' and PE."ProductType" = 'Signature' 
group by PE."Amount", PC."Amount", PE."Id") as "PUP";
```

Comment: Use `COALESCE(PC.Amount, 0)`

Comment: Where ? @smvenk

Comment: `SELECT PE.Amount, COALESCE(PC."Amount",0) as PCAmount FROM ...`

Comment: And how to do a sum of all the columns?

Comment: Usualy `SELECT SUM(<column_name>) FROM ...` or `SELECT <category_column>, SUM(<column_name>) FROM ... GROUP BY <category_column>`

Answer (score 0):

If you simply would like to replace null values by 0, you can use COALESCE:

```
SELECT
pe.amount, COALESCE(pc.amount,0)
FROM productentry AS pe
JOIN users u ON u.id = pe.userid
LEFT JOIN productconsummation pc ON pc.productentryid = pe.id
WHERE userid = 1 AND pe.status = 'Active' and pe.producttype = 'Signature' 
GROUP BY pe.amount, COALESCE(pc.amount,0)
```

Take care that this must both be done within the select part and within the group by part of your query. Also take care that you need to write '0' instead of 0 in case your amount column is of kind varchar.
Furthermore, I generally recommend to only write SQL key words in UPPER CASE and the rest of your queries or commands in lower case. And if possible, using SQL key words as table names or column names should be avoided. So in your case, the table "user" should be renamed to "users", "username" or similar. I have applied these suggestions to my example, but of course, it's your decision if you follow them.